# Vim yank and paste via a shared file

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I posted this question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45826678/1082727) first, as I did not know about "Vi and Vim beta".

How to augment Vim yank and paste, so when I yank, Vim writes the content to a file? When I paste, it uses the content from the file. I want to have a system wide file which serves as a global buffer.

Context: I run Vim in different tmux splits on a remote server (over ssh). I want seamlessly copy and paste between Vims in tmux splits. I tried a bunch of plugins, but none of them worked, thus the question.

Comment: and the same question here, where do you get stuck ? what have you tried. Do you want to overwrite `y` and `p` ore have 2 new commands (YankToFile, CopyFromFile)?

Answer (score 0):

Use register `+`. For yanking use `"+y` which yanks to register `+` and for pasting use `"+p` which copies content from `+`.

I use the following maps in my vimrc to copy to system clipboard

```
noremap <leader>y "+y<CR>
noremap <leader>p "+p<CR>
```

Comment: use tmux，tmux buffer to unname register, uname register to tmux buffer

https://github.com/tracyone/t-vim/blob/master/autoload/te/tmux.vim

Comment: @c0de222 Using  the + register does not work for copying between vims in different tmux splits, unfortunately.

Comment: @tracyone Can you please provide more details how to use the script? Somehow it did not worked out for me. I moved tmux.vim to ~/.vim/bundle/tmux.vim and "set runtimepath^=~/.vim/bundle/tmux.vim" . However, regular y and p did not paste between vims in tmux splits.

Comment: https://github.com/tracyone/t-vim/blob/master/rc/tmux.vim#L23-L24

Comment: Alternatively, add these three mappings to your vimrc: `vmap <C-c> :w! ~/.vbuf<CR>`, 
`nmap <C-c> :.w! ~/.vbuf<CR>`, 
`nmap <C-v> :r ~/.vbuf<CR>`.